# x_axis is not organized in scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, scatter-plot

I am using below code

```
x1=[-30,-22.28,-14.95,22.77,60,97.22,134.45,171.68,180,185]
plt.scatter(y=b1,x=x1)
plt.xticks(x1)
```

Below is the output:-
[image]

In this as you can see, the axis is not organized.

I tried with figsize but it is not helping.

I want to organize it, also is there any way that I can customize gap between those points on x_axis?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set limits and make both axis equal.

```
plt.axis('equal')
plt.set(xlim=(<minvalue>, <maxvalue>), ylim=(<minvalue>, <maxvalue>))
```

Consult this documentation for more details and comprehensive examples

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html

Comment: With xlim also it is not working. It is showing same output. Values clustered around the end. Also I want to show values of x1 only on x_axis.